# C++ Algorithm: How can I improve efficiency of this code? [Big-O]

Tags: c++, algorithm

How can I re-write the code below in a way that I can improve his efficiency?

```
Fraction Polynomial::solve(const Fraction& x) const
{
    Fraction rc;

    auto it = poly_.begin();
    while (it != poly_.end())
    {
        Term t = *it;
        //find x^exp
        Fraction curr(1, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < t.exponent_; i++)
        {
            curr = curr * x;
        }
        rc += t.coefficient_ * curr;
        it++;

    }
    return rc;
}
```

What is the current Big-O notation for this code? [I think it's O(N^2)]

Comment: It is `O(n * m)`

Comment: This question is more suitable on CodeReview. You may migrate your question there.

Answer (score 4):

I'll cite Numerical Recipes, chapter 5, because it's fun:

> We assume that you know enough never to evaluate a polynomial this
>   way:
>
> `p=c[0]+c[1]*x + c[2]*x*x +c[3]*x*x*x + c[4]*x*x*x*x;`
>
> or (even worse!),
>
> `p=c[0]+c[1]*x+c[2]*pow(x,2.0)+c[3]*pow(x,3.0)+c[4]*pow(x,4.0);`
>
> Come
>   the (computer) revolution, all persons found guilty of such criminal
>   behavior will be summarily executed, and their programs won’t be! It
>   is a matter of taste, however, whether to write
>
> `p=c[0]+x*(c[1]+x*(c[2]+x*(c[3]+x*c[4])));`
>
> or
>
> `p=(((c[4]*x+c[3])*x+c[2])*x+c[1])*x+c[0];`
>
> ...

At least this will remove the `m` out of your `O(m*n)` implementation (where `m` is the exponent and `n` the polynomial order).